# Git Add Multiple HTTPS Links

Tags: git

Is there a way to add multiple users with **HTTPs** in Git? 
For example I have:

```
$ git remote add origin https://JREAM@bitbucket.org/company/site.git
```

But if another user wants to pull, they have to use my password, can't I do something like this:

```
$ git remote add origin https://%user%@bitbucket.org/company/site.git
```

**I do not want to use SSH** keys because I keep having problems implementing *(And I suppose I need a company deployment read-only key, but then everyone will need that key on their computer)*.

I want the user to be able to type in their **Username** and **Password** to do a pull.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  If another user wants to pull, then they start with `git clone https://otheruser@bitbucker.org/company/site.git`, and they use their own password.

Comment: Its to pull into the exact same place on the server, so Im not the only one who has to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, git remotes are specific to a given local repository, they aren't stored on the server. So unless everyone's stuck using the same local checkout, each person should just be able to set up the remote for the checkout they're using with their own account:

```
git remote add origin https://<username_here>@bitbucket.org/company/site.git
```

(Obviously for that to work each user will need to have their own BitBucket account with access to the repository.)

If, for some reason, you still want to have git prompt for both a username AND password, (Everyone is sharing the same local checkout for some reason?) then you can just get rid of the `<user>@` part of the URL completely. Git will then prompt you for both a username AND password every time you try to fetch or push:

```
git remote set-url origin https://bitbucket.org/company/site.git
```